# No flash mode pictures

Tags: canon, canon-400d

OK so I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to photography.  But here's the thing when I try to  Take a picture in the no flash mode in the dark it won't take a picture but if I go into some light and no flash mode it will take a picture no problem so I'm just wondering  is there something I'm doing wrong. All I want to do is take some pictures of the stars in the sky at night time and I am having no luck, please help. Thanks in advance for any advice or answers given.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Autofocus turned on the camera will not release the shutter until it can confirm focus. This pretty much never happens with the night sky unless the moon is in the frame. The stars are too dim and too small for the AF system to work on them.

Switch the lens to Manual Focus (MF on the AF/MF switch). Manually focus the lens using Live View, then leave the lens focused there for the rest of your session.

For best results also use manual exposure mode. A good starting point might be ISO3200, the aperture wide open (the lowest f-number your lens allows), and exposure as 500 divided by the focal length of your lens. (Example: for a 50mm lens, expose for 10 seconds) Of course, such long exposures will require a tripod.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You are using some automatic mode that will not allow the camera to take a picture if it will be "underexposed".</s>

Your best bet is to switch to manual mode; you might also need to use bulb mode.

It's all in the manual...

Comment: It's got nothing to do with exposure mode. Canon cameras will allow a dark frame with the lens cap on in automatic modes, they'll just flash a warning in the viewfinder.

Comment: @MichaelC, I completely forgot about AF confirmation... I almost exclusively use release priority (Nikon).